# Android "hover" event in custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, android-gesture

I have a custom layout that I have written that basically just displays a bunch of **ImageViews**. I am handing **onTouch** events for all the ImageViews in my layout.

However, if a user touches one *imageView* and then drags over another *ImageView*, I would like to be able to handle that as well.

How would I go about capturing this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this example is useful: http://www.anddev.org/viewtopic.php?p=11603

it relies on tracking the event with MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE. the coordinates could be checked to determine when the element enters/exits a cell.

it uses drawview, but hopefully the same can be done w/imageview

Comment: Yeah, that is probably one way, though it seems like its not all that efficient to loop through all of my views and look for a hit.

What I would prefer is to handle touch at the Layout level, and if there is an imageView at that touch location, dispatch a touch event to that imageView.

Comment: I tried handling the motion event at the imageView level, and giving up focus if I determine that the finger is no longer over the imageView.  However, once I clear focus, and the finger (still pressed) goes over another imageView, that imageView will not receive focus.  Is there any way for me to get this behavior?

I appreciate any help.